# How to save array of Strings in Node Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I Have an array of String which I want to save in Mongodb in Node/express, it is saving Empty array in Mongodb

```
const multiImagesSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    names:Array
})
```

```
import ImgArray from '../../Model/multiImages.js'

let imgNames = req.files.map(imgName=>{ 
            return imgName.originalname  
        })

      // console,log(imgNames)
       //result in console:   ['Apple,png', 'Grapes.png','Ornage.png','Banana.png'] 

        const imageArray = new ImgArray(imgNames)
        await imageArray.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the object with properties defined in schema Model to the creation function (in your case the object with `names` property). You are passing the `imgNames` array. Change you code like this:

```
await ImgArray.create({ names: imgNames });
```

Answer (score 0):

your model need to have a field that accepts array like this:

```
const ImgArraySchema = mongoose.Schema({
names: [{
type: String,
required: true
}]
})
```

then to save an array, do it like this:

```
const imageArray = new ImgArray({names: imgNames})
const imgarray = await imageArray.save()
.catch((err) => (res.status(500).send({err: err.message})))
if (imgarray) {
return res.status(200).send({success: true, imgarray})
}
return res.status(400).send({success: false, error: ""})
```