# How to save an array of strings in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have found a few similar questions on stack overflow like this one:
[How to save array of Strings in Node Mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68972336/how-to-save-array-of-strings-in-node-mongodb)
[Mongoose - Save array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509611/mongoose-save-array-of-strings)

but I cant figure out why my method is not working

I am trying to save the string of arrays "jobType".
context: I am creating an app where people can post jobs.
each job can have multiple types.

here is my job model::

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  content: { type: String, required: true },
  imagePath: { type: String, required: true },
  state: { type: String, required: true },
  substate: { type: String, required: true },
  address: { type: String, required: true },
  jobType: { type: [String] },

  creator: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true }

});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Job", postSchema);
```

this is the API used to save the data on MongoDB:
I am 100% sure that the data is getting to the API correctly.
the parameter "req.body.jobtype" contains all the info as a string.
I am trying to use JSON.parse to change the string into an array but its not working.
when I check MongoDB, an empty array is being stored

```js
const Job = require("../models/job");
exports.createJob = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('create job api hit')

  const url = req.protocol + "://" + req.get("host");
  const post = new Job({
    content: req.body.content,
    imagePath: url + "/images/" + req.file.filename,
    creator: req.userData.userId,
    state: 'new',
    substate: 'new',
    address: req.body.address,
    jobtype: JSON.parse(req.body.jobtype) // fix: not storing correctly
  });
  post
    .save()
    .then(createdJob => {
      res.status(201).json({
        message: "Job added successfully",
        post: {
          ...createdJob,
          'pecker':'pecker hecks out',
          id: createdJob._id
        }
      });
   
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.status(500).json({
        message: JSON.stringify(error)
      });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo. In your model, you defined `jobType` property, but when saving the data, you are passing it as `jobtype`.

So, instead of this:

```js
jobtype: JSON.parse(req.body.jobtype)
```

Do this:

```js
jobType: JSON.parse(req.body.jobtype)
```